# generating duplicate values (fill down?) when parsing XML into Dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I have a problem parsing XML into a data frame using Python. When I print out the values, some values seem to 'filldown', or repeat themselves. (see column adres). Does anyone one know what could be wrong?

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
import xmltodict
import json

tree = et.parse('20191125_DMG_PI.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

df_cols = ["status", "priref", "full_name", "detail", "adres"]
rows = []

for record in root:
    for child in record:
        s_priref = child.get('priref')
        for field in child.findall('Address'):
            s_address = field.find('address').text
            #for sub in field.findall('address.country'):
            #   s_country = sub.find('value').text if s_country is not None else None
        for field in child.findall('name'):
            s_full_name = field.find('value').text
        for field in child.findall('name.status'):
            s_status = field.find('value').text
        for field in child.findall('level_of_detail'):
            s_detail = field.find('value').text
        rows.append({"status": s_status,
                     "priref": s_priref,
                     "full_name": s_full_name,
                     "detail": s_detail,
                     "adres": s_address},)

out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)
print(out_df)
```

[image]

Comment: you should clear all variable before every loop - you could assign empty strings. If you don't do this then they have still value from previous loop - if new item doesn't have own value.

Comment: how do I do this? I'm new to this. Thank you for helping :)

Comment: normally assign empty strings to variables at the beginning of loop `for child in record:` - `s_status = ""`. `s_priref = ""`, etc.

Comment: @OlivierVanDhuynslager Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved the issue so the question is marked accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, `findall()` returns an empty `list` if there is nothing found which matches the search criteria, so in the loop

```py
for field in child.findall("..."):
    # this is only performed if child.findall() doesn't return empty
```

The consequence of this, in this case, is that `s_address`, `s_full_name`, `s_status`, and `s_detail` do not necessarily get assigned to a new value on each iteration of the outer loop. Hence, they will retain the value from the most recent iteration that the respective `child.findall()` clause returned non-empty.

The simple way to fix this is to assign them all to some initial value on each iteration of the outer loop, i.e.

```py
for child in record:
    s_piref = child.get('piref')
    s_address = ''
    s_full_name = ''
    s_detail = ''
    s_status = ''
    # ...
```

Although it might be better (perhaps more 'pythonic') to do something like this:

```py
# Store child.findall() and field.find() keys in a dict
dict = {'Address' : 'address', 
        'name' : 'value', 
        'name.status' : 'value', 
        'level_of_detail' : 'value'}

# To store the reference keys
ref = ["adres", "full_name", "status", "detail", "piref"]

for record in root:
    # Initialize a second dict from the same keys mapping to 
    # empty strings instead
    s = dict.fromkeys(dict.keys(), '')
    s["piref"] = "piref"
    for key in dict:
        for field in child.findall(key):
            s[key] = field.find(m[key])
    rows.append(dict(zip(ref, s.values())),)
```

Which should work just the same as the other method but makes it easier to add more keys/fields as needed.